# Run GUI app from command line

Tags: display

I would like to launch X application using buttons on 3.2 inch TFT. I the beginning I am trying to lauch app from the remote bash console.

My X are running:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ps aux |grep xserver
pi        2435  0.0  0.2   3044   796 ?        S    22:34   0:00 xinit /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :0 -auth /tmp/serverauth.UVIbNw3DC8
```

then I was trying following:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# export DISPLAY=:0
root@raspberrypi:~# matchbox-keyboard
No protocol specified
Cannot open display
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: try running `export DISPLAY=:0 matchbox-keyboard` as one line.

Comment: running it as one line has no effect. That's not the problem

Comment: What is the source of the TFT display?  How is it wired?  Is there any output on it at all?  Were there any instructions to configure it?  I wrote a free book (https://leanpub.com/pi) and cover some on TFT and X-Windows - search for Frame Buffer TFT driver.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just hit an authentication problem with X. You need to authorize your cookie.

First off, get your cookie by running `xauth list $DISPLAY`

```
Sample output:

pi@server0 ~ $ xauth list $DISPLAY
raspberrypi/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Now, run `xauth add` and use your cookie as the argument/input.

```
pi@server0 ~ $ xauth add raspberrypi/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
pi@server0 ~ $
```

After you hit enter, it shouldn't give any output. Try running your app again.